# How to check if interface is a a pointer to a slice

Tags: go, pointers, reflection, slice

I know how to check if an interface is a pointer:

```
func isPointerArray(i interface{}) bool {
    if i == nil {
        return false
    }
    if reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return false
    }
}
```

But how can I check if that pointer is a slice? `TypeOf` is a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value's kind is `reflect.Ptr`, you may use [`Value.Elem()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Elem) to get the pointed value, and you may compare its kind to `reflect.Slice`.

This is how it would look like:

```
func isPtrSlice(i interface{}) bool {
    if i == nil {
        return false
    }
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return false
    }
    return v.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Slice
}
```

But there's one catch though. If the value passed is a pointer to slice type but the value itself is the `nil` pointer, this will report `false`. Understandable, as there is no pointed value whose type could be a slice. This may or may not be what you want.

If you want `true` even for `nil` pointer values (that are of pointer to slice types), you may use `reflect.Type` instead of `reflect.Value`. This works for `nil` pointers too, because even though there is no pointed value, there is still a pointed type (called the *base type*).

```
func isPtrSlice2(i interface{}) bool {
    if i == nil {
        return false
    }
    t := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return false
    }
    return t.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Slice
}
```

Testing the above functions:

```
vals := []interface{}{
    nil,
    "a",
    &image.Point{},
    []string{},
    &[]string{},
    (*[]string)(nil),
}

for _, v := range vals {
    fmt.Printf("%-14T isPtrSlice: %-5t, isPtrSlice2: %t\n",
        v, isPtrSlice(v), isPtrSlice2(v))
}
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YkRyKWheyRH)):

```
<nil>          isPtrSlice: false, isPtrSlice2: false
string         isPtrSlice: false, isPtrSlice2: false
*image.Point   isPtrSlice: false, isPtrSlice2: false
[]string       isPtrSlice: false, isPtrSlice2: false
*[]string      isPtrSlice: true , isPtrSlice2: true
*[]string      isPtrSlice: false, isPtrSlice2: true
```

As you can see in the last line (where the value is a `nil` pointer of type `*[]string`) `isPtrSlice()` returns `false` while `isPtrSlice2()` returns `true`.

Comment: for arrays, one can use `reflect.Array`, e.g. `elem.Kind() == reflect.Slice || elem.Kind() == reflect.Array`

Comment: some icza quality response right there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var value interface{}
    value = &[]int{1, 2}

    if res, ok := value.(*[]int); ok {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: One constraint is that I don't know the type.